# Rails Link Helpers not getting localised inside .text.erb files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this action inside a mailer template in Ruby on Rails 3.2:

```
# password_reset.text.erb

<%= edit_password_reset_path(@user.password_reset_token) %>
```

Unfortunately, when I hit that link I get a strange routing error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :locale=>"Ze92D45dUPpfwsgbFmpYeg"}
```

It is strange that the `locale` seems to contain the `password_reset_token` here rather than the locale (e.g. `en` or `de`).

So I guess that `edit_password_reset_path` is not getting localised automatically and that is causing the error?

How could that be fixed?

Here's some more info:

```
class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController  
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
  end
end

# routes.rb
scope '(:locale)' do
  resources :password_resets
  ....
end
```

Comment: Show us the: relevant portion of the routes file and the relevant portion from the translations yml.

Comment: OK, just posted some more info above. There are no translations involved here so far I think. The key problem seems to be that the `password_reset_token` is posted as the `locale` parameter which is wrong.

Comment: What does rake routes show for the `password_resets` resource?

Comment: Posted above. It's definitely the locale that is causing the trouble. If I remove the `scope '(:locale)' do` block from my `routes.rb`, the link works. But I need to localize it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the token as a query param:

```
edit_password_reset_path(@user, password_reset_token: @user.password_reset_token)
# Passing in the @user fulfills the :id section of the url.
```

By doing `edit_password_reset_path(@user.password_reset_token)` you are providing the reset token to the `:locale` section.

To provide locale as well:

```
edit_password_reset_path(@user, locale: "de", password_reset_token: @user.password_reset_token)
```

Comment: Thanks!! You just saved my ***. This is the final version of my code: `<%= edit_password_reset_path(@user, :locale => I18n.locale, :password_reset_token => @user.password_reset_token) %>`

Comment: Perhaps this might more closely resemble the link desired --- it will match the Controller edit method in place already: <%= edit_password_reset_path(@user.password_reset_token, :locale => "#{I18n.locale}") %>